# What are some algorithms for finding a closed form function given an integer sequence?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math

I'm looking form a programatic way to take an integer sequence and spit out a closed form function. Something like:

Given: 1,3,6,10,15

Return: n(n+1)/2

Samples could be useful; the language is unimportant.

Comment: It may just be a lack of mathematical knowledge but this problem doesn't seem bounded enough.

Comment: Suggestion for bounds: find a closed form function given exactly 10 integers, if possible, else return null.  Unfortunately something like that oversimplifies this problem to a great extent.  So much so that it almost becomes worthless.

Comment: My main concern was that I was over-thinking the problem, and that there was some well known way to go about it. Turns out that's not the case, and in fact I'll need considerably more thought than I've already invested

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This touches an extremely deep, sophisticated and active area of mathematics. The solution is damn near trivial in some cases (linear recurrences) and damn near impossible in others (think 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, ....) You could start by looking at [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for example and looking at Herb Wilf's [incredible](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) book (cf. page 1 (2e)) on the subject but that will only get you so far.

But I think your best bet is to give up, query Sloane's comprehensive [Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/) when you need to know the answer, and instead spend your time reading the [opinions](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/OPINIONS.html) of one of the most eccentric personalities in this deep subject.

Anyone who tells you this problem is solvable is selling you snake oil (cf. page 118 of the Wilf book (2e).)

Comment: Some fantastic links; exactly what I was looking for. I had a feeling the answer would be complicated. I think perhaps I need more knowledge of the subject matter before I can ask the right questions. Thanks!

Comment: Waugh, I took too long texifying my solution.  You beat me by a mile :)

Comment: You might also want to look at the book "Concrete Mathematics."  You may find it more accessible than Wilf's book.

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that it implicitly assumes that there is *one* correct function, when in fact there are an infinite number of closed form functions that go through any specified finite set of points -- as just 1 example, a degree-n polynomial will go through any n+1 given points. But the bigger problem is: there is no way to choose which function of these functions is "best". Why? One reason is because the next number in the sequence **could be anything**. I'm -1ing until you mention this up front.

Comment: @j_random_hacker please, lower your -1 so we can discuss this matter rationally.

Comment: @LucasAlonso: My -1 is no obstacle to rational discussion.

Answer (score 10):

There is no *one* function in general.

For the sequence you specified, [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/) finds 133 matches in its database of interesting integer sequences.  I've copied the first 5 here.

> [A000217](http://oeis.org/A000217) Triangular numbers: a(n) = C(n+1,2) = n(n+1)/2 = 0+1+2+...+n.
> 0, **1, 3, 6, 10, 15**, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, 210, 231, 253, 276, 300, 325, 351, 378, 406, 435, 465, 496, 528, 561, 595, 630, 666, 703, 741, 780, 820, 861, 903, 946, 990, 1035, 1081, 1128, 1176, 1225, 1275, 1326, 1378, 1431
>
> [A130484](http://oeis.org/A130484) Sum {0<=k<=n, k mod 6} (Partial sums of [A010875](http://oeis.org/A010875)).
> 0, **1, 3, 6, 10, 15**, 15, 16, 18, 21, 25, 30, 30, 31, 33, 36, 40, 45, 45, 46, 48, 51, 55, 60, 60, 61, 63, 66, 70, 75, 75, 76, 78, 81, 85, 90, 90, 91, 93, 96, 100, 105, 105, 106, 108, 111, 115, 120, 120, 121, 123, 126, 130, 135, 135, 136, 138, 141, 145, 150, 150, 151, 153
>
> [A130485](http://oeis.org/A130485) Sum {0<=k<=n, k mod 7} (Partial sums of [A010876](http://oeis.org/A010876)).
> 0, **1, 3, 6, 10, 15**, 21, 21, 22, 24, 27, 31, 36, 42, 42, 43, 45, 48, 52, 57, 63, 63, 64, 66, 69, 73, 78, 84, 84, 85, 87, 90, 94, 99, 105, 105, 106, 108, 111, 115, 120, 126, 126, 127, 129, 132, 136, 141, 147, 147, 148, 150, 153, 157, 162, 168, 168, 169, 171, 174, 178, 183
>
> [A104619](http://oeis.org/A104619) Write the natural numbers in base 16 in a triangle with k digits in the k-th row, as shown below. Sequence gives the leading diagonal.
> **1, 3, 6, 10, 15**, 2, 1, 1, 14, 3, 2, 2, 5, 12, 4, 4, 4, 13, 6, 7, 11, 6, 9, 9, 10, 7, 12, 13, 1, 0, 1, 10, 5, 1, 12, 8, 1, 1, 14, 1, 9, 7, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 9, 2, 14, 1, 2, 8, 12, 2, 5, 10, 3, 5, 11, 3, 8, 15, 3, 14, 6, 3, 7, 0, 4, 3, 13, 4, 2, 13, 4, 4, 0, 5, 9, 6, 5, 1, 15, 5, 12, 11, 6
>
> [A037123](http://oeis.org/A037123) a(n) = a(n-1) + Sum of digits of n.
> 0, **1, 3, 6, 10, 15**, 21, 28, 36, 45, 46, 48, 51, 55, 60, 66, 73, 81, 90, 100, 102, 105, 109, 114, 120, 127, 135, 144, 154, 165, 168, 172, 177, 183, 190, 198, 207, 217, 228, 240, 244, 249, 255, 262, 270, 279, 289, 300, 312, 325, 330, 336, 343, 351, 360, 370, 381

If you restrict yourself to polynomial functions, this is easy to code up, and only mildly tedious to solve by hand.

Let [image: f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_nx^n], for some unknown [image: a_0\ldots a_n]

Now solve the equations
[image: y_0=f(0)=a_0]
[image: y_1=f(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n]
[image: y_2=f(2)=a_0+2a_1+4a_2+\cdots+2^{n-1}a_{n-1}+2^na_n]
…
[image: y_n=f(n)=a_0+na_1+n^2a_2+\cdots+n^{n-1}a_{n-1}+n^na_n]
which simply a system of linear equations.

Comment: You gave an example algorithm, while the "correct" answer asserted that no such algorithm exists.  Interesting.

Your answer assumes that the sequence is finite, which I think is a correct assumption.

Comment: @Martin: ephemient clearly stated that the solution state was restricted to polynomials of degree n, which can always be fit to a finite set of n points.

Comment: Small correction: a polynomial of degree n can always be fit to a finite set of n+1 points.

Comment: +1. This should be the correct answer IHMO. The most important point to make is that the problem is sorely underconstrained, and I think the list of 5 different plausible functions for 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 you gave demonstrates that quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is guaranteed to be expressible as a polynomial, I think you would be able to use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) (or any suite that offers regression fitting of data).  If your correlation is exactly 1, then the line is a perfect fit to describe the series.

There's a lot of statistics that goes into regression analysis, and I am not familiar enough with even the basics of calculation to give you much detail.

But, [this link to regression analysis in R might be of assistance](http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/Education/Lectures/R/regression.htm#lr_models)

Comment: You could form the polynomial by taking all of the roots given, say a, b and c, and write it in the form f(x) = (x-a)*(x-b)*(x-c). But that doesn't mean that they are not other polynomials that would satisfy it.

Answer (score 2):

The Axiom computer algebra system includes a package for this purpose.  You can [read its documentation here](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/GuessingFormulasForSequences).

Here's the output for your example sequence in FriCAS (a fork of Axiom):

```
(3) -> guess([1, 3, 6, 10, 15])

                 2
                n  + 3n + 2
(3)  [[function= -----------,order= 0]]
                     2
Type: List(Record(function: Expression(Integer),order: NonNegativeInteger))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is ill-posed. Given any finite number of integers in a sequence with
no generating function, the next element can be anything.

You need to assume something about the sequence.  Is it geometric?  Arithmetic?

Comment: All kinds of sequences. Maybe a 'sequence' is given where there isn't a generating function. I'd like to be able to handle that case as well. I'm at square one right now, so if you think there is some way I should re-factor the question, I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

If your sequence comes from a polynomial then divided differences will find that polynomial expressed in terms of the Newton basis or binomial basis. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton_series).

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answers; a simple method can be implemented bu using [Pade approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant); in two words, assume your sequence is a sequence of coefficients of the Taylor expansion of an unknown function, then apply an algorithm (similar to the continued-fraction algorithm) in order to "simplify" this Taylor-expansion (more precisely: find a rational function very close to the initial (and truncated) function. The Maxima program can do it: look at "pade" on the page: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_28.html

Another answer tells about the "guess" package in the FriCAS fork of Axiom (see previous answer by jmbr). If I am not wrong; this package is itself inspired from the Rate program by Christian Krattenthaler; you can find it here: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/rate/rate.html Maybe looking at its source could tell you about other methods.